# How to convert base64 string to a PIL Image object

Tags: python-3.x, character-encoding, base64, python-imaging-library

```
import base64
from PIL import Image

def img_to_txt(img):
    msg = ""
    msg = msg + "<plain_txt_msg:img>"
    with open(img, "rb") as imageFile:
        msg = msg + str(base64.b64encode(imageFile.read()))
    msg = msg + "<!plain_txt_msg>"

    return msg

class decode:
    def decode_img(msg):
        img = msg[msg.find(
        "<plain_txt_msg:img>"):msg.find(<!plain_txt_msg>")]
        #how do I convert the str 'img', encoded in base64, to a PIL Image?

while 1:
    decode.decode_img(img_to_txt(input()))
```

How do I convert the string to a PIL Image object, I was thinking of using the function frombytes() withing the Image module from PIL.

Answer (score 18):

[PIL's `Image.open`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.open) can accept a string (representing a filename) or a file-like object, and
an [`io.BytesIO`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#binary-i-o) can act as a file-like object:

```
import base64
import io
from PIL import Image

def img_to_txt(filename):
    msg = b"<plain_txt_msg:img>"
    with open(filename, "rb") as imageFile:
        msg = msg + base64.b64encode(imageFile.read())
    msg = msg + b"<!plain_txt_msg>"
    return msg

def decode_img(msg):
    msg = msg[msg.find(b"<plain_txt_msg:img>")+len(b"<plain_txt_msg:img>"):
              msg.find(b"<!plain_txt_msg>")]
    msg = base64.b64decode(msg)
    buf = io.BytesIO(msg)
    img = Image.open(buf)
    return img

filename = 'test.png'
msg = img_to_txt(filename)
img = decode_img(msg)
img.show()
```

Comment: `msg = msg[msg.find(b"<plain_txt_msg:img>")+len(b"<plain_txt_msg:img>"):TypeError: must be str, not bytes`

Comment: I used the solution above but I already had a base64 encoded string that I sent from an android application. So then I was able to cut out that first line of decode_img function and was left with:
def decode_img(msg):
    msg = base64.b64decode(msg)
    buf = io.BytesIO(msg)
    img = Image.open(buf)
    return img