# How to save an image as a variable?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-imaging-library

Now, I have a python game that has sprites, and it obtains the images from files in its directory. I want to make it such that I do not even need the files. Somehow, to pre-store the image in a variable so that i can call it from within the program, without the help of the additional .gif files

The actual way i am using the image is

```
image = PIL.Image.open('image.gif')
```

So it would be helpful if you could be precise about how to replace this code

Comment: Doesn't tkinter has an image object? Qt has one, named QImage.

Comment: but you have to open the image each time from the file

Comment: Why? Why do you think it's a good idea to embed images in code?

Comment: And when the program ends, what happens to the image data?

Comment: i want to convert the .py into .exe, and i want everything to bo neat. And i only want to carry one file around

Comment: @rojanghosh The data should still be there so that i can access it again next time i run the code

Comment: "How do I package my program into an exe" is a much better question than "how  do I put images into python scripts". And the answer definitely won't be "Put all the data in your python script".

Comment: See [Process to convert simple Python script into Windows executable](//stackoverflow.com/q/2136837).

Comment: I know how to convert it into an executable, but I did not know how to save the image in the code, so that the executable can handle it

Comment: @Aran-Fey: I think you're being a bit harsh. I think it's perfectly reasonable to embed some image data in a script under some circumstances. It may not be a best practice, but it's still a reasonable solution.

Comment: @BryanOakley Hmm, I think I can see what you mean. But that really wasn't intentional. I smelled an XY problem, so I asked a question to find out if I was right, and then I simply stated that it would've been better to ask about the X rather than the Y. I can see why you would think that I was... hmmm... *cold*, but it's really all factual and neutral.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Continuing @eatmeimadanish's thoughts, you can do it manually:

```
import base64

with open('image.gif', 'rb') as imagefile:
    base64string = base64.b64encode(imagefile.read()).decode('ascii')

print(base64string)  # print base64string to console
# Will look something like:
# iVBORw0KGgoAAAANS  ...  qQMAAAAASUVORK5CYII=

# or save it to a file
with open('testfile.txt', 'w') as outputfile:
    outputfile.write(base64string)


# Then make a simple test program:

from tkinter import *
root = Tk()

# Paste the ascii representation into the program
photo = 'iVBORw0KGgoAAAANS ... qQMAAAAASUVORK5CYII='

img = PhotoImage(data=photo)
label = Label(root, image=img).pack()
```

This is with tkinter PhotoImage though, but I'm sure you can figure out how to make it work with PIL.

Comment: Could you please specify how to implement this in PIL, I am having difficulties

Comment: I don't use PIL an haven't installed it, so I can not give you advice on this other than to suggest you look at: [How to convert base64 string to a PIL Image object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45122994/how-to-convert-base64-string-to-a-pil-image-object).

Answer (score 2):

Here is how you can open it using PIL.  You need a bytes representation of it, then PIL can open a file like object of it.

```
import base64
from PIL import Image
import io

with open("picture.png", "rb") as file:
    img = base64.b64encode(file.read())

img = Image.open(io.BytesIO(img))
img.show()
```

Comment: What would the value of `img` be an alias for?

Comment: Where's your explanation?

Comment: We got there at the end.