# How do I store images in order to train a CNN?

Tags: python, image, conv-neural-network

I'm trying to make a Convolutional 2D network that trains on image values, but, unfortunately, I can't seem to find a way to store each image as a variable.

(Before anyone asks, I have looked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52559429/how-to-save-an-image-as-a-variable/52561405#52561405), but base-64 encoding doesn't exactly work with convolutional neural networks.)

I have also tried `matplotlib.image.imread` and `glob.glob`, but these, again, do not store the actual image, but the data behind the image itself. And, again, I can't exactly train a neural network with metadata.

Does anyone have any ideas that I could use to do this?

Comment: What do you mean by _store_, exactly?

Comment: @AMC I'm using keras, so I need an array to fit my model on. I'm trying to figure out how to keep that array of images without just storing the metadata.

Comment: That's what you wrote in your post, I was hoping for something more specific.

Comment: @AMC no that's about it of what I meant by storing...

Comment: Pardon? I'm not sure I understand what you mean.

Comment: @AMC Uh... I'm trying to get an array from an image for training my neural network, but it's not matching up at all with my data. I'm asking if there is any way I can actually encode each pixel of the image into a full 2D array. Does that help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read the image in using the pillow library and convert it to a numpy array so you can feed it into your network.

https://kite.com/python/examples/4887/PIL-convert-between-a-pil-%60image%60-and-a-numpy-%60array%60

If you need to save those arrays into a file for later use you can use [np.savez](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.savez.html).

Comment: Oh, I'm afraid this doesn't exactly work - it stores the image as an array. I'm looking for a way to store the image itself as a variable. Thanks for answering, though!

Comment: @ShreyasShridharan Arrays and variables are very different things.

Comment: I am not understanding yout purpose then.  An array can be a variable if you want.  In the context of a neural network you need an array to actually train it.

Comment: You can save a list of numpy arrays with with [np.savez](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.savez.html).

Comment: @jawsem The problem I'm encountering is that the array I get from this is populated with 255s in a 255x4 2D array. This does not match my data in the slightest. Do you have any ideas why this is happening?