# I can't decode a base64 encoded image and use it with PIL

Tags: python, flask, python-imaging-library

I want to open on my flask server an image I sent from a web page using pillow.
So I first encoded the image in base64 using the `btoa` function in javascript and then make a post request to my server. My image is sent and decoded succesfully but I get this error when I try to use it using pillow:

`PIL.UnidentifiedImageError: cannot identify image file <_io.BytesIO object at 0x000002464BE233B0>`

My JS function :

```js
function handleImage (){
  image = btoa(URL="../static/images/images_final.jpg");

  fetch("/predict" ,{
     method: "POST",
     body: JSON.stringify({image})
  })
}
```

My Flask Endpoint :

```py
@app.post("/predict")
def predict_image():
    req = request.get_json(force=True)

    b64Image = req["image"]
    buf = base64.b64decode(b64Image)
    image = Image.open(io.BytesIO(buf))

    
    return TF_MODEL.predict(image)
```

I followed the instruction of this post :
[How to convert base64 string to a PIL Image object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45122994/how-to-convert-base64-string-to-a-pil-image-object)

But nothing works...

Thanks for your help !

Comment: You might need to use `formats=` to give it a hint.

Comment: More specifically, use `formats=['JPEG']`, you can see a list of supported formats at [pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/handbook/image-file-formats.html](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/handbook/image-file-formats.html).  Notice that the formats are case sensitive.

Comment: Try `print(b64Image[:20], buf[:20])`

Comment: adding the `formats=` is not working

Comment: Oh okay I get it, when I print I get `Li4vc3RhdGljL2ltYWdl b'../static/images/ima'` so that's not the image that is converted but its URL, that's why it doesn't work...Thanks !

Comment: Cool... always worth inspecting stuff that doesn't work 